# How do I create a command add-in for onenote

Tags: command, add-in, onenote

Can you help me with some sort of tutorial for how to do this?
I`m currently using both VS 2015 and 2017.

Comment: What is a command add-in?

Comment: From what I have understood it is the term for an addin that lives in the OneNote ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the sample at http://github.com/onenotedev/vanillaaddin

There is info there on creating an addin as well as a standalone console app that controls onenote.

Comment: I have some issue with the setup project in the solution. After building it the install menu-item is disabled. I have installed the install extension for VS 2015.

Comment: All I get is an setup.exe file, not the .msi.

Comment: Ok, I got thing to work OK. What I now would like to to is use some of the stuff shown in the OneNote Windows Universal sample when it comes to adding a page. And for that matter use the sample in the Vanilla solution. Can you guide me on that one?

Comment: Unfortunately, the samples use two different APIs and are not compatible. The Vanilla addin is client side only and requires OneNote on Win32.  The universal sample works with notebooks stored in Sharepoint Online or OneDrive.